# lightning component not showing up in a visual force page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I could not show the `lightning app` in a visual force page.

However, if I include `weiParent2` component in the community lightning builder the component will show up.

What's the issue to use the lightning in a VF page?

## Lightning Login App

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp"
                  implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"
                  access="GLOBAL"
>
    <aura:dependency resource="c:weiParent2"/>
    <c:weiParent2 />
</aura:application>
```

## VF page

```
<html>
<head>
    <apex:includeLightning/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>
    Hello World Wei
</h1>

<div id="lightning"/>

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:lightningLoginApp", function () {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:weiParent2",
            {label: "This is the lightning button!"},
            "lightning",
            function (cmp) {
            debugger

            });
    });
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you dont need to add <c:weiParent2 /> in your app, only declare it as a dependency and create it as you already are inthe vf pags script

Comment: Your VF page doesn't really look like a VF page since there's not an `<apex:page>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pattern that I've been pretty successful with.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
  <apex:includeLightning/>
  <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:lightningLoginApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent(
          "c:weiParent2",
          {label: "This is the lightning button!"},
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
              console.log("Component created!");
              //debugger ?? what's this for?
          });
      });
  </script>
  <div id="lightning"></div>
</apex:page>
```

- You need to include the lightning/lightning.out.js script
- I think you want to have the div after your script.
- Also glls' comment is, I think, relevant. The component you create dynamically probably shouldn't be in you app

Maybe refactoring to this pattern is worth a try.

Comment: newBike is using `<apex:includeLightning/>` which is the recommended way to include the lightning out runtime.

Comment: Hi @John if I want to re-render the component and the re-render event should be controlled by a parent container Visualforce  page. How could I do that?

Comment: Checked it out... there's actually a couple of outdated references in the documentation, but `<apex:includeLightning/>` is certainly valid. I edited my answer.